# Passing direct parameters to a Controller#method when testing via RSpec

Tags: ruby-on-rails, testing, controller, rspec

Normally to pass parameters via in RSpec we do:

```
params[:my_key] = my_value
get :my_method
```

Where `my_method` deals with what it received from params. But in my controller I have a method, which takes args directly i.e.:

```
def my_method(*args)
  ...
end
```

How do I call the method with those args from within the test? I've tried `get :my_method(args)` but Ruby interpreter complains about syntax error.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As far as I can see, you can't do that. You can extract `my_method` into a helper, or into a library, and then test it with Rspec, if you need to test `my_method` directly. Or you can structure your controller tests so that the code in `my_method` is exercised as part of a controller action that can be called by one of the standard HTTP verbs (get, post, put, delete).

Ultimately it has to be possible to reach any code that your controller uses by setting up tests with `get`, `post`, etc, because otherwise Rails couldn't do it and your app wouldn't work. This may make testing inconvenient, but it might also be telling you that `my_method` would be better off living outside the controller.